# Map showing blur when i load the static Google map

Tags: android, image, google-maps-static-api

> In my Chat Applicaion i am using share location for this i used static map than the map loaded successfully but the image showing blur,i want to show static map like Whatsapp just good resolution image so please guide me..

**Url**

```
public static String local(String latitudeFinal, String longitudeFinal){
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+latitudeFinal+","+longitudeFinal+"&zoom=14&size=230x100&scale=2&markers=color:red|"+latitudeFinal+","+longitudeFinal;
}
```

**Xml File:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/left_map_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:id="@+id/left_map_time"
                    android:text="11 minute ago"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_single_tick"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="10"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Java Code:**

```
viewHolderSenderMapView.setIvMapPhoto(Util.local(senderMap.getMapModel().getLatitude(),senderMap.getMapModel().getLongitude()));
```

Comment: in your url, try changing size param.. you are sending `size=230x100`

Comment: I used but still remain same

Comment: please someone guide me why this happen?